# Image not displaying,in php code at localhost

Tags: php, image, localhost

I have problem in this code part (image source is correct). I am a beginner.

```
<?php echo '<img class="I" src="C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmysql\GRAPHICS\call.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:150px;  hspace:20";> ;'?>
```

Error on inspecting over image,and going to network then reloading:

> Provisional headers are shown Referer:
>   http://localhost/phpmysql/hbcs_web/insert.php Sec-Fetch-Dest: image

Comment: you cannot use local file paths ( `C:\XAMPP...` ) in a webpage like that on a webserver- the path needs to be relative to the webserver root or other folder ( /images/graphics/... ) etc ~ or `/graphics/call.png`

Comment: @RamRaider    <?php echo '<img class="I" src="GRAPHICS\call.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:150px;  hspace:20";> ;'?>   Even after using this it failed.

Comment: firstly web pages use a `forward slash` - `/` rather than backslash. Secondly, without a leading slash the path you have used tells the server that the image is in a sub-folder in the same directory as the current html page.

Comment: why you are printing whole image tag

Comment: You just need to print image name from datebase in src Attribute something like that: ``<img class="I" src="<?php echo 'assets/img/' . $var['image']; ?>" alt="Avatar" style="width:150px;  hspace:20";>``